# SQL Server - 1 column update, is lock required?

Tags: sql-server-2008, atomic

I have a need for unique identifiers in my application. To that end, I created a table in my  database that only contains 1 column 'unique_id" (BIGINT) and 1 row.
The idea is to use a stored procedure to get the next identifier when I need it. I figured a 1-line operation like this would do the job:

```
UPDATE identifier_table SET unique_id = unique_id + 1 OUTPUT INSERTED.unique_id
```

Can someone confirm if this operation is atomic, or do I need to setup a lock on the table?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you not use an identity field?

Comment: +1 to HGLEM, why not just use identity, or if on Denali a sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the answers!  Figured it would serve the same purpose, keeping just one row in the table - don't think/know how to update an identity column.  I realize space is cheap these days, so would I better off just inserting rows and cleaning up every now and then?

Comment: Not to mention, I would like to know for other scenarii as well :o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is atomic. It is just a single update statement, and will have no problem at all with concurrency since that will be managed by the engine with update locks. You can use OUTPUT as shown, or you can do something like this:

```
DECLARE @unique_id bigint;

UPDATE identifier_table
SET
   @unique_id = unique_id + 1,
   unique_id = unique_id + 1;

SELECT @unique_id uniqueid;
```

If you make `@unique_id` an OUTPUT parameter, then you can get the value without a select statement or use it easily in another stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks ErikE! A little late to the party, but it confirms my findings :o)